# SQLite Can't Verify Insert

Tags: android, sqlite

Can anybody see why this won't work. I'm trying to add a simple row to a table and then confirm that it was added correctly. When I try to query the table, my program crashes. My head hurts from staring at this for so long.

```
addNewGame(1);

Cursor cursor2 = db.query(myDBOpenHelper.GAMES_TABLE, new String [] {"MAX("+GAME_COLUMN+") AS GC"}, null, null, null, null, null);
System.err.println("made it this far");     
String temp = cursor2.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GC")); //crash!!!
System.err.println("didn't get here);


private static void addNewGame(int g) {
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase db = DBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
    newValues.put(GAME_COLUMN, g);
    newValues.put(CIV_COLUMN, "");
    db.insert(myDBOpenHelper.GAMES_TABLE, null, newValues);
}
```

> thread exiting with uncaught exception

Also, here is the code from where the table was created:

```
private static final String GAMES_CREATE =  "create table " +
            GAMES_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID +
            " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            GAME_COLUMN + " text not null, " +
            CIV_COLUMN + " text);";
db.execSQL(GAMES_CREATE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Nothing Check this.that the cursor will be null?
just try this code.

```
if(cursor2.getcount>0)
{
cursor2.moveTofirst();
String temp = cursor2.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GC"));
}
```

try this it`s work.

Comment: That worked! I don't understand why I would have to check for a null cursor when I just inserted a record, but at this point I don't care. If I could give you 1000000 +1's I would. Thanks very much!